# Trying to use the arcade library on Python3 with Debian 10 errors with pyglet_ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ffmpeg, arcade

I've been trying to use the arcade library this morning with python3 but keep getting nothing but errors.

My environment is Debian 10 (buster)

I checked first to ensure I have python 3 installed, this confirmed as Python 3.7.3

I double checked (according to the arcade library website [arcade linux installation instructions](https://arcade.academy/installation_linux.html) and ran the install for python3 to make sure that pip and the required libraries were installed.

I then ran the command to install the library

```
sudo pip3 install arcade
```

And to test it, copied and pasted the happy_face.py example.  However when I tried to run it I got a slew of errors.  This seems to be directly related to the arcade installation and if I just run a python script (test.py) with just one line

```
import arcade
```

At the terminal with

```
python3 test.py
```

I get the following errors

> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavcodec.so.58.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavformat.so.58.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libswresample.so.3.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavfilter.so.7.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavutil.so.56.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libswscale.so.5.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavcodec.so.58.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavformat.so.58.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libswresample.so.3.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavfilter.so.7.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavutil.so.56.*
>
> Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location:
>   /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libswscale.so.5.*

I have used the following terminal command to identify the version of OpenGL installed

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

Which returned

> OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 18.3.6

I have also tried the terminal command

```
sudo pip3 install pyglet-ffmpeg
```

Which returns

> Requirement already satisfied: pyglet-ffmpeg in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.1.4)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyglet>=1.4.0a1 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyglet-ffmpeg) (1.5.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: future in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from
>   pyglet>=1.4.0a1->pyglet-ffmpeg) (0.18.2)

Any assistance would be appreciated.  I've tried to be as concise as I can, but if more information is required, I'll gladly supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system had these files, but at the wrong path. I just copied them to the right path and the error went away.

```
$ cd ~/.local/
$ ln -s lib lib64
$ cd lib64/python3.7/site-packages/
$ cp -r pyglet_ffmpeg/linux_x86_64/ pyglet_ffmpeg2/
```

Answer (score 0):

I never even thought to see if the libraries were installed anywhere else.
Turns out all I needed to do was issue the command

```
$ cd ~/.local/
$ sudo ln -s lib lib64
```

Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: You should rather accept the answer then to (re)post it as another one.